# multiple integrals and matrices (complex elements) from numeric-prelude

Tags: haskell, numerical-analysis

I need to calculate integrals of the form

```
/t     /x
| P(x)*| P(y) dydx
/t0    /t0
```

where P is a function `R -> C^(nxn)`, generally a matrix, and I want to do this in Haskell. I have achieved this for scalar functions:

```
import Numeric.GSL.Integration
import Data.Complex
import Data.List

prec :: Double
prec = 1E-9

integrate :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Double
integrate f a b = fst $ integrateQNG prec f a b 

integrateC :: (Double -> Complex Double) -> Double -> Double -> Complex Double
integrateC cf a b = (integrate (\x -> realPart (cf x)) a b :+ integrate (\x -> imagPart (cf x)) a b)

multipleIntegration :: Int -> (Double -> Complex Double) -> Double -> (Double -> Complex Double)
multipleIntegration n f a =  foldl' (\ acc g' -> (\ x -> integrateC (g'*acc) a x)) (\_ -> 1:+0) (replicate n f)
```

This works so far, although it is quite slow for n>5.

Now I need to extend this calculation to matrices, I tried this with numeric prelude, because I can take functions as elements of a matrix.
I am able to integrate a matrix of `Double -> Complex Double`, but my actual goal to multiply a matrix inside the integral fails, first my code:

```
import MathObj.Matrix as Mat
import Algebra.Ring as AR
import Control.Applicative
import qualified Prelude as P
import Prelude hiding ((*))
import Number.Complex as NC
import Numeric.GSL.Integration
import Data.List

type Complex a = NC.T a

prec :: Double
prec = 1E-9

testMat :: Mat.T (Double -> Complex Double)
testMat = Mat.fromRows 2 2 [[\x-> 0.5 +: 2*x,\y-> cos y +: sin y],[\x-> 0.1*x +:x,\_-> 1 +: 1]]

integrateC :: (Double -> Complex Double) -> Double -> Double -> Complex Double
integrateC cf a b = (integrate (\x -> real (cf x)) a b +: integrate (\x -> imag (cf x)) a b)

integrate :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Double
integrate f a b = fst $ integrateQNG prec f a b 

integrateCMat' :: Mat.T (Double -> Complex Double) -> Double -> Mat.T (Double -> Complex Double)
integrateCMat' cmf a =  ((\f -> integrateC f a ) <$> cmf)

multipleIntegrationMat :: Int -> Mat.T (Double -> Complex Double) -> Double -> Mat.T (Double -> Complex Double)
multipleIntegrationMat n mf a =  integrateCMat' ( testMat * (integrateCMat' testMat a)) a
```

Here, `multipleIntegrationMat` is just a testing function, I didn't use a fold, so n is superfluous.
The error message is:

```
matmul.hs:27:59:
No instance for (C (Double -> Complex Double))
  arising from a use of `*'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (C (Double -> Complex Double))
In the first argument of `integrateCMat'', namely
  `(testMat * (integrateCMat' testMat a))'
In the expression:
  integrateCMat' (testMat * (integrateCMat' testMat a)) a
In an equation for `multipleIntegrationMat':
    multipleIntegrationMat n mf a
      = integrateCMat' (testMat * (integrateCMat' testMat a)) a
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I understand that there is no instance for function multiplication. What would be the best way for such an instance? On the other hand, in the scalar example, the multiplication works, although the complex data type is taken from `Data.Complex`. When I try the scalar example with `Number.Complex` I get the same error.

What can I do to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but... it seems to me you actually describe _P_ : (ℝ → ℂ)ⁿˣⁿ, rather than what you mean to, namely _P_ : ℝ → ℂⁿˣⁿ.

Comment: yeah, that is true, I have a matrix and this matrix contains functions of the same parameter, so mathematically it is:P:R->C^(nxn) one parameter which maps via P into a nXn matrix which holds complex values. In Haskell I have to map the integral into the matrix, at least that was my way to do it, and then I have a matrix of functions, which depend on a real parameter. this should represent the mathematical context, I hope so :) But the problem is the same, I somehow have to multiply 2 functions.

Comment: Ok I see, you simply put in the same parameter in all matrix entries. But what's the point of this, wouldn't a `Double -> Mat.T (Complex Double)` immediately solve the problem _and_ be more straighforward, conceptually?

Comment: Well, when I think it through and try to write in correctly then it should be: P: R -> (R->C)^nxn -> C^nxn , I think this should be correct, but still, I have a matrix of functions which I need to integrate, and apply a value to it some time later.

Comment: Well I tried this out, but I had a problem with the integral. When I apply the integrate function to the matrix, then I get the desired result, but how can I integrate: `Double -> Mat.T (Complex Double)` when the lib funtion provides only integration over `Double->Double`?

Comment: Could you make your last comment as an answer? I have to think it through, but as i see it, you draw the integrateC function inside the matrix, what happens then? cmf is now `Double -> Mat.T (Complex Double)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do

```
integrateCMat' :: (Double -> Mat.T (Complex Double))
                -> Double -> Double
                 -> Mat.T (Complex Double)
integrateCMat' cmf a b = Mat.fromRows n m integratedRows 
     where (n,m) = Mat.dimension(cmf undefined)
           integratedCell idx = integrateC (cellFunction idx) a b
           cellFunction idx = (\(Mat.Cons arr) -> arr ! idx) . cmf
           integratedRows = [ [ integratedCell(i,j) | i<-[1..n] ] | j<-[1..m] ]
```

but I agree that it's rather ugly, though Haskell's lazyness should ensure that not all matrix entries would be calculated in each integration step.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried your code, and with some minor modifications it worked (I had trouble with Mat.Cons, so I changed to Mat.index and modified the list comprehension to `integratedRows = [ [ integratedCell (i,j) | i<-[0..(n-1)] ] | j<-[0..(m-1)] ]`).
But then I still can't multiply the matrices inside the integration, like this:
`let appval = \x -> ($x) <$> testMat` in
`integrateCMat'' (appval*(integrateCMat'' appval 0 )) 0 1`
Am I missing something?

Comment: The double-integration should be completely straightforward now, `integrateCMat'' (\x -> integrateCMat'' testMat t0 x) t0 t`. Not so?

Comment: indeed, this works. But here comes the but, what I really need is that the first integration returns a function, which again is fed to the integral **but** inside the integral is multiplied with the same matrix of the first integration. complicated to explain, in my post the first line :): matrix function `P(y)` is integrated with respect to `y`, from `t0` to `x` which is: `f(x)=int^x_t0 P(y) dy` this function is multiplied with `P(x)` and then integrated with respect to x: `g(t)=int^t_t0 P(x)*f(x)dx`. You can say that in f(x) the matrix P(y) is multiplied with identity, which I omitted.

Comment: This chained integration is part of the _multiplicative integral_ which is the general solution to the differential equation:
`d/dt y(t) = P(t) y(t)`, where `y` and `P` can be matrices, in my case `y` is a vector and `P` is a matrix. The solution I try to implement is a series: `O(t)=I+int^t_t0 P(x)*I dx + int^t_t0 P(x)*int^x_t0 P(y)*I dy dx +...` and so on, it works for scalars, though it is very slow (see the post for implemention)

Comment: Ah yes... still, where's the problem with: `integrateCMat'' (\x -> testMat x * integrateCMat'' testMat t0 x)) t0 t`?

Comment: That works, great! Somehow I did something somewhere wrong. 
`integrateCMat'' (\x -> (appval x) * integrateCMat'' appval t0 x) t0 t`, I forgot the additional lambda, well that was some heavy working, thanks a lot. But there is no way to apply this for the _matrix of functions_ case, right? That would just be more elegant :)